# Special character handling in android volley Android-N version

Tags: json, character-encoding, android-volley, android-7.0-nougat, android, gson

I have a code which apparently work's fine untill Android 6.0, for handling special character's like swedish character's. But this does not work well in android N 7.0 version, any solution's, also HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE is deprecated. 
This is the extra line of code which helped me to make it work upto android 6.0

```
 response.headers.put(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, response.headers.get("content-type"));
```

As of now i am getting character's like Å,å,Ä,ä,Ö,ö, as "&#1234" etc. kind of value's under response. Any modification or active antidepricated codes, would be helpful,,

```
      @Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        Response<T> resp = null;

        //handling special character's and content type based on request type
        //http may be deprecated, but we are handling it over org.apache library in gradle
        response.headers.put(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, response.headers.get("content-type"));
        String json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        switch (mJsonResponseType) {

            case JSON_OBJECT:
                resp = Response.success(gson.fromJson(json, mResponseClass), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                break;

            case JSON_ARRAY:
                // NOTE: For this to work properly the mResponseClass must be set to an array type, e.g. MyClass[]
                resp = (Response<T>) Response.success(gson.fromJson(json, mResponseClass), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                break;

            default:
                resp = (Response<T>) Response.success(json, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                break;
        }
        return resp;

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));

    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}
```

Comment: What does response.headers.get("content-type") return? And which is the expected character encoding? The website's one.

Comment: "Content-Type" -> "application/json; charset=utf-8", well, it requires the same format which is coming ,,weird

Comment: try replacing String json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers)); with String json = new String(response.data, "UTF-8"));

Comment: same result, ä got replaced with &#246;

Comment: When you print it to the devices screen what character does it print and which would be the expected character? &#246; is one way of encoding a character.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Volley has inbuilt way of handling it's Request class, where i found something like, private static final String DEFAULT_PARAMS_ENCODING = "UTF-8";
So the change's i made to specefic section with a method, where html tagged data was coming in response  :)

```
 public static Spanned fromHtml(String html) {
            if (NullCheckUtils.isEmpty(html)) {
                html = "";
            }
            html = (html.replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&gt;", ">"));
            Spanned result;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                result = Html.fromHtml(html.trim(), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
            } else {
                result = Html.fromHtml(html.trim());
            }
            return result;
        }

String response=fromHtml("&#1234").toString();
Log.d(TAG,response);
```